# Running special length encoding for a string containing ASCII?

Tags: java, string, encoding, compression, ascii

Is it possible to run length encoding on an input string but to a more compressed level? I want to be able to compress the amount of characters in the string by a significant amount by specifying the location of each value. For example:

Input string: `ABBAACDCCDD`

Traditional output: `1A2B2A1C1D2C2D`

Desired output: `3A(1:1,2:3)3B(2:2)3C(1:5,2:7)3D(1:6,2:10)`

Where the first value in `(1:1)` represents the position of the value, the second value represents how many in that position and on, and the coma separates positions to be placed.

I know that this would be inefficient for small strings such as the example above, but I intend to implement this into a constructor that takes a string that will range from `~200` values to `~5000`

EDIT:

How would I do this with where the string being inputted is in ASCII and regular format? I've taken a look at the Javadoc for the `java.util.regex.Pattern` class and it looks like it only accepts either ASCII or regular text. Is it possible to have both?

Comment: How is either of those a "compression" of the original?

Comment: Is it possible to turn a string into some (weird) descriptor of the positions of various characters in it? Sure, go right ahead.

Comment: @Andreas In the case of long strings, (with the length included in the question) it would be efficient, however for small strings it would be inefficient, as I stated in the question...